# What's the geometrical interpretation of the following map?

Tags: geometry, dynamical-systems

Let $T = S^1 \times D^2$ be the solid torus, where $D^2 = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| \le 1\}$ and $S^1 = [0, 1]$ mod $1$. Then we define a map $f : T \to T$,
$$f(t, z) = (g(t), \frac{z}{4} + \frac{1}{2} e^{2 \pi t i}),$$
where $g : S^1 \to S^1,\; g(t) = 2 t$ mod $1$ is the doubling map.

I don't understand the geometrical interpretation of $\frac{z}{4} + \frac{1}{2} e^{2 \pi t i}$. Can someone explain me, please?

Comment: For each fixed $t$ the image of $D^2$ under this mapping is a circle with center at $\frac{1}{2}e^{2\pi t i}$ and with radius $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Can you explain me why, please? Thank you!

Comment: Let's analyze the mapping step by step. What is $z \mapsto \frac{z}{4}$? It is just a scaling transformation. So, if you had a unit disk on complex plane, this mapping transforms it into $\vert z \vert \leqslant \frac{1}{4}$. Transformation $u \mapsto u + u_0$ is always a translation: it just shifts all points in the same direction. Composing the latter mapping with the former, we get that scaled disk was translated to other point of plane. Hence it is still a disk with the same radius but a different center. A center of the original disk was located at $0$. The rest is an easier part, I hope.

Comment: @Evgeny Thank you!